# Why are physical systems continuous?

Tags: spacetime, discrete

To my (very limited) knowledge, physical systems (fluids, for example) can't have jump discontinuities.

Why? 
Which fundamental laws can this be derived from, if any?

This question is related to 
[Is spacetime discrete or continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33273/is-spacetime-discrete-or-continuous) and perhaps the answers are connected, but I'm not confident that *not everywhere discrete* implies *not discontinuous anywhere*.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1324/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/261340/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The continuity of physical systems applies only to the scales we perceive. At smaller scales we know it breaks down when individual atoms and molecules come into play. At even smaller (Planck) scales we can't really imagine continuous systems.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thank you! I'm apparently very bad at searching for the right things on SE... Those answer my question quite well!